# I can't change the capitalisation on the input word without an error showing up. I have used toLowerCase()

Tags: javascript, console.log

```
const getUserChoice = (userInput=userInput.toLowerCase()) => {
  if (userInput==='rock'||userInput==='paper'||userInput==='scissors') {
  return userInput;
     }
  else {
  console.log('Error!');
    }
  };

console.log(getUserChoice('Scissors'));
```

//This does not seem to work. Only if I type in the words in all lowercase letters.

Comment: Remove the change to lowercase from the parameter declaration to inside the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const getUserChoice = (userInput=userInput.toLowerCase()) => {
```

In this line you create the default value of the function argument, which will be `undefined` unless `userInput` exists in the scope. It doesn't manipulate the argument you pass.

E.g. a function like this:

```
const hello = (name="stranger") => console.log(`hello, ${name}`)
```

will say "hello, stranger" if called with no arguments, and "hello, Scissors" if called as `hello("Scrissors")`.

When you call the function: `getUserChoice('Scissors')` the default argument is overriden by what you have passed, and `userInput` inside your function is `"Scissors"`.

You need to do the conversion inside the function body:

```
const getUserChoice = (userInput) => {
   userInput=userInput.toLowerCase()
   /* now userInput is the lowercase version of the argument you pass */
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
const getUserChoice = (userInput) => {
  userInput = userInput.toLowerCase()
  
  if (userInput === 'rock' || userInput === 'paper' || userInput === 'scissors') {
    return userInput;
  } else {
    return 'Error!'; //changed to return
  }
};
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @adiga, guidance appreciated.

Comment: @Kasalwe shameless, but please have a ook at my answer. The problem and solution is obvious to an experienced developer, but it took me way longer to write it because I took the time to explain what was wrong, why, what were the incorrect assumptions and what the code really does to provide an answer that not only explains what should be changed, but also why.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing

```
const getUserChoice = (Input) => {
  let userInput = Input.toLowerCase();
  if (userInput==='rock' || userInput==='paper' || userInput==='scissors') {
    return userInput;
  } else {
    console.log('Error!');
  }
};
console.log(getUserChoice('Scissors'));
```